# convert array to string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want the text to be printed without commas.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Reverse</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="rev">
Enter the string : <input type="text" name="str"/>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="rev1()" /><br>
reverse of given string : <input type="text" name="res"/>
</form>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function rev1(){
var a=rev.str.value;
var b=[];
var i,j=0;
    for(i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    b[j]=a[i];
    j++
}
//rev.res.value=b;
alert(b);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I give the input as `abc` I am getting an output as `c,b,a`, but I want it as `cba`.

Comment: `[].toString()` is [implemented](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.2) as `[].join()` (which uses a comma as a separator, [by default](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.5), ie `[].join(',')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You may reverse your string using javascript built-in functions:

   ```
           <html>
           <head>
           <title>Reverse</title>
           </head>
           <body>
           <form name="rev">
           Enter the string : <input type="text" name="str"/>
           <input type="button" value="click" onclick="rev1()" /><br>
           reverse of given string : <input type="text" name="res"/>
           </form>
           <script type="text/JavaScript">
               function rev1(){
                   var a=rev.str.value;
                   var b=a.split("").reverse().join("");
                   //rev.res.value=b;
                   alert(b);
               }
           </script>
           </body>
           </html>
   ```
2. You may also transfer join your array elements to become a string

   ```
           <html>
           <head>
           <title>Reverse</title>
           </head>
           <body>
           <form name="rev">
           Enter the string : <input type="text" name="str"/>
           <input type="button" value="click" onclick="rev1()" /><br>
           reverse of given string : <input type="text" name="res"/>
           </form>
           <script type="text/JavaScript">
               function rev1(){
                   var a=rev.str.value;
                   var b=[];
                   var i,j=0;
                       for(i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                       b[j]=a[i];
                       j++
                   }
                   //rev.res.value=b;
                   alert(b.join(""));
               }
           </script>
           </body>
           </html>
   ```

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
alert( b.join("") )
```

You could also reverse a string more easily by:

```
"hello".split("").reverse().join("")
//"olleh"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `document.getElementById().value.reverse().join("");`